# is RequestDelegate an endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to asp.net core 3.0 and struggling in understanding the concept of endpoint. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0
says:

*An endpoint is something that can be:
a.Selected, by matching the URL and HTTP method.
b.Executed, by running the delegate.*

Below is the template code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    });
}
```

can I say the `RequestDelegate`

```
async context => {
   await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
}
```

is an endpoint?

Comment: it's not an endpoint accessible from the outside (like what configured in the Startup class). It's just like a callback to invoke the next middleware in the current pipeline (the `Delegate` suffix shows that clearly, it's just a delegate - or callback).

Comment: An endpoint is something you can refer/point to, so no. In the example above, `/` is the endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I say the RequestDelegate
>
> ```
> async context => {
>    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
> }
> ```
>
> is an endpoint?

No, it is a request delegate, instead of a endpoint. When an HTTP GET request is sent to the root URL `/`(endpoint): The request delegate shown executes. "Hello World!" is written to the HTTP response.

```
    endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    });
```

But, using the above code, the MapGet method defines an endpoint. As [the documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#routing-basics) said:

[image]

Besides, you could also check the MapGet method:

[image]